# Adding background image in CSS to Advanced Custom Field (ACF)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm a little stuck on this section. I've only added ACF php in html when the background image was located in the html. Now I have 2 shapes in my css with pseudo elements. How would I add the php so it works on wordpress?

HTML

```
<section class="main-content-section home">
         <section class="hero-section" style="background-image: url(images/home-hero@2x.jpg);"></section></section>
```

CSS

```
.hero-section:before,.home .hero-section:after{position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; content: ""; background-image: url(../svgs/Rectangle.svg); background-position: left top; background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 64.25%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;}
.home .hero-section:after{background-image: url(../svgs/Rectangle-Copy.svg); background-position: right bottom; left: auto; top: auto; right: 0; bottom: -46%; width: 63.125%;}
```

Comment: After should have two colons before it: .hero-section::after

Comment: Would using an nth element be a way around it?

Comment: don't really need to use the pseudo element for it - You could just echo out whatever dynamically after the section and style that however you want. like a `<div class="theFakePseudo"><img class="whateverIcon" src="<?php echo get_field('your_acf_image_field')['sizes']['thumbnail'];?>" alt="It's an icon"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably include inline `<style>` tags in your template, using the image from the ACF field, as you cannot use an inline style on a pseudo selector in the HTML directly.

Ie:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .home .hero-section:after { 
         background-image: url('<?= get_field('your_acf_image_field')['url'] ?>'); 
    }
</style>
```